Testing equality of coefficients from two different regressions with Seemingly Unrelated Regressions
I am running two regressions, one nested in the other.
$$ y = \beta_1 X  + \epsilon_1$$
$$ y = \beta_2 X  + \beta_3 Z  + \nu_2$$
I would like to assess whether the coefficient of X is the same or not in the two equations $$\hat\beta_{1} \neq \hat\beta_{2} ?$$
Basically, I am wondering whether adding the covariate Z significantly changes the association between y and X.
I tried to do this with R as follows:
# install.packages("systemfit")
library(systemfit)

# Specify the two equations
eq2 <- y ~ x + z
eq1 <- y ~ x

# Combine models into a system
system <- list(eq1 = eq1, eq2 = eq2)

# Fit the SUR model
fit <- systemfit(system, method = "SUR", data=data_full2)

# Test equality of X coefficients across models
linearHypothesis(fit, "eq1_x = eq2_x")

However, when I look at the fit results of eq2, I find something very different from when I was calculating each regression separately. (using  lm(y ~ x + z, data=data_full2)). I understand that the results may vary in both cases, but it is a very big difference, as the coeff was 0.1  in the restricted model and 0.05 in the full model when computed separately, whereas both become around 0.1 in the SUR calculation. So of course, the results from my linearHypothesis(fit, "eq1_x = eq2_x") command tell me that the difference is not significant.
Is it normal that my coefficients change so much when running them using the systemfit() command compared to two independent lm() ? Should I still trust the result of the analysis that the coeffs are actually not significantly different in both equations?
